# How to determine $[L:K]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to determine $[\mathbb{Q}(7^{1/4}):\mathbb{Q}]$.
I know I have to find a basis but I don't really see how to do it.

I would seem logic to me to just take powers of $7^{1/4}$, until some power is in $\mathbb{Q}$.
This means in my case $\{1,7^{1/4},7^{2/4},7^{3/4} \} $ should be a basis and $[\mathbb{Q}(7^{1/4}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$, but I don't really see the argument behind it.

Comment: You can determine the minimal polynomial of $7^{1/4}$ instead and look at the degree. Since $x^4-7$ is an Eisenstein polynomial....

Comment: In this case finding the dimension is easier than finding a basis, though neither is very difficult. Observe that, essentially by definition, $\mathbb{Q}(7^{1/4}) = \mathbb{Q}[x] / (x^4 - 7)$. You must show that $x^4 - 7$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ and then quote the standard result that the degree of an extension by an irreducible polynomial is just the degree of the polynomial. The basis, if you want it, is $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$, which is the same basis you have identified under the isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}[x] / (x^4 - 7)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(7^{1/4})$.

Answer (score 2):

Here I just replace L,K with my notation E,F.
Let $F=\mathbb{Q}$, $E=\mathbb{Q}(7^{1/4})$, $\alpha = 7^{1/4}$.

There is some proposition that says if $\alpha$ is algebraic over F, then $[F(\alpha):F]=n (n:=$ degree of the minimal poly. of $\alpha$ over F) and $\{1, \alpha ,...,\alpha^{n-1}\}$ is a F-basis of $F(\alpha)$. I think the result is trivial, and you should know the proof in general.

Sketch of proof:
Consider the evalution map $\psi: F[x]\rightarrow F[\alpha]$, that maps $f(x)$ to $f(\alpha)$.

For the case $ker(\psi)\neq 0$, we have $\alpha$ is algebraic over F.
And ker is generated by some monic polynomial f(x), $ker(\psi)=<f>$, which is the minimal poly. of $\alpha$ over F. In your example, $f(x)=x^4-7$.
Moreover,  $F[\alpha]\simeq F[x]/<f>$ is a field, so $F(\alpha)=F[\alpha]$.

Let n:=the degree of f.
Note that $f(\alpha)=0$, $\alpha^n$ is a linear combination of $\{1, \alpha ,...,\alpha^{n-1}\}$, and f is minimal poly. so $\{1, \alpha ,...,\alpha^{n-1}\}$ is a F-basis of $F(\alpha)$.